# SDWebImage in UICollectionview cells disturbs cells on scroll

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, sdwebimage

I have a UICollectionView with Cells having images in them. These images are downloaded from an url. The issue is that whenever I scroll the UICollectionView, the cells are reloaded and duplicate images appear in the cells for a few seconds.

This completely disturbs the cells. Below is some code I have

```
var pictureCollectionSource = new PictureCollectionSource(picRefined);
  pictureCollection.Source = pictureCollectionSource;
  picturecollectiondelegate = new PictureCollectionViewDelegate(picRefined);
  pictureCollection.Delegate = picturecollectiondelegate;
```

PictureCollectionViewDelegate.cs

```
public class PictureCollectionViewDelegate : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
    {
        public delegate void CellClickedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e);
        public event CellClickedEvent CellClicked;
        private IEnumerable<ProfileValues> picRefined;

        public PictureCollectionViewDelegate(IEnumerable<ProfileValues> picRefined)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            this.picRefined = picRefined;
        }

        public override CoreGraphics.CGSize GetSizeForItem(UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {

                var width = (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width / 4);
               return new CoreGraphics.CGSize(width, width);

        }
    }
```

PictureCollectionSource.cs

```
public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = collectionView.DequeueReusableCell (cell_id, indexPath) as PictureCollectionCell ?? PictureCollectionCell.Create();

            var data = picRefined.ElementAt(indexPath.Row);

            cell.UpdateCell(data);
            return cell;
        }
```

UpdateCell

```
internal void UpdateCell(ProfileValues mdata)
        {


            var mUrl = "someurl";

   var manager = SDWebImageManager.SharedManager;
   manager.ImageCache.MaxCacheAge = 86400;
            SDWebImageDownloader mDownloader = manager.ImageDownloader;

            var authToken = "SomeToken"";


            mDownloader.SetHttpHeaderValue(authToken, "Authorization");
            mDownloader.SetHttpHeaderValue("application/json; odata=verbose", "Accept");
            mDownloader.SetHttpHeaderValue("f", "X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED");


            try
            {
                mDownloader.DownloadImage(
                 url: new NSUrl(mUrl),
     options: SDWebImageDownloaderOptions.ProgressiveDownload,
                progressBlock: (receivedSize, expectedSize) =>
                {
                    // Track progress...
                },
                completedBlock: (image, data, error, finished) =>
                {

                    if (image != null && finished)
                    {
                        InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                        {

                            this.imgProfilePic.Image = image;
                        });

                    }
                    if (error != null)
                    {
                        InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                        {
                            this.imgProfilePic.Image = errorImage;
                            this.imgProfilePic.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(52, 31, 71);
                            //this.imgProfilePic.Layer.CornerRadius = this.imgProfilePic.Frame.Size.Width / 2;
                            this.imgProfilePic.ClipsToBounds = true;
                            this.imgProfilePic.Layer.BorderWidth = 3.0f;
                            this.imgProfilePic.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.White.CGColor;
                        });
                    }
                }


              );
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

**EDIT**

I tried using static cells as suggested in the comments. I added 16 cells in the storyboard UICollectionView. Modified my UICollectionVIewSource as below:-

```
List<string> cellIds = new List<string>(){"pic_collection_cell","cell_2","cell_3","cell_4","cell_5","cell_6"
    ,"cell_7","cell_8","cell_9","cell_10","cell_11","cell_12","cell_13","cell_14","cell_15","cell_16"};

 public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell (UICollectionView collectionView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
  {
   int cellIndex = (int)indexPath.Item;

   if (cellIndex >= cellIds.Count) {
    cellIndex = 0;
   }

   UICollectionViewCell cell = collectionView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIds [cellIndex], indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell;

    profImage = new UIImageView (cell.Frame);
    profImage.Image = UIImage.FromFile ("ic_account.png");

    cell.AddSubview (profImage);


            return cell;
        }
```

But with this, only the first cell seems to show the imageview even though the debugger shows the imageview added to other cells as well.

[image]

How can I solve this? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You are reusing cells. When you start downloading image, just cancel previous download. This worked for me.

Comment: @AkshayNalawade Thanks for the reply. Can you elaborate on how I can do it?

Comment: - (void)cancel:(nullable SDWebImageDownloadToken *)token;
Use above method from SDWebImageDownloader class. Sorry for Objective C code!

Comment: @AkshayNalawade Thank you. Ill try converting it to c#.

Comment: It is better not to reuse cells when you are downloading images from an URL. Keep cell static and download images. It'll solve your issue.

Comment: @NirmitDagly Your approach will also work.

Comment: @NirmitDagly Thanks for the reply. I have a list of Url's that need to be loaded in the cells. I know how to supply a list to a collectionview source and futher to cells, can you help me with an example on how to work with static cells?

Comment: @NirmitDagly I have tried https://github.com/widescape/StaticCollectionViewCells to achieve what I need.. but the image in only the first cell shows. Any idea?

Comment: Please update your code with the use of this library, So that I can try to help you.

Comment: @NirmitDagly PLease see my edited question

Comment: Ok.. let me look into this.

Comment: collectionView.DequeueReusableCell  -- What this method do? Is this a custom method?

Comment: @NirmitDagly it is similar to   
`UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifiers[cellIdentifierIndex] forIndexPath:indexPath];`